# join 3 tables with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

Here i want to join this three tables namely `salary`,`payroll` and `attendance`  .first i want to join `salary.salary_template_id` with `employee.salary_template_id` and after that i want to join `employee.user_id` with `attendance.user_id` in order to get the basic salary of each `user_id`.how can i join?
My salary table looks like this

I am getting this error

> Unknown column 'tbl_employee_payroll.salary_template_id' in 'on clause'

```
salary_template_id  salary_grade    basic_salary    overtime_salary
1                        a             10000    
2                        b             15000
```

My employee table looks like this

```
payroll_id  user_id     salary_template_id  
    1         1                NULL 
    2         36                2   
    3         43                1
```

My attendance looks like this

```
 attendance_id  user_id     leave_category_id   date_in     date_out    attendance_status 


    13           36              0            2017-01-02    2017-01-02       1
    14           36              3            2017-01-04    2017-01-04       3
```

here is my code

```
public function attendance_report_by_empid($user_id = null, $sdate = null) {

    $this->db->select('attendance.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('employee.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('salary.*', FALSE);

    $this->db->from('attendance');
    $this->db->join('salary', 'salary.salary_template_id  = employee.salary_template_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('employee', 'employee.user_id  = attendance.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('attendance.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('attendance.date_in', $sdate);
    $this->db->where('attendance.date_out <=', $sdate);

    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();

    return $query;
}
```

my result should be like this

```
attendance_id   user_id     leave_category_id   date_in     date_out    attendance_status  salary
    13           36              0            2017-01-02    2017-01-02       1              1000
    14           36              3            2017-01-04    2017-01-04       3              1000
```

Comment: Would you like to tell us what the problem is?

Comment: the problem is joining not take place andd getting error

Comment: Would you like to tell us what the error you are getting is?

Comment: `Unknown column 'tbl_employee_payroll.salary_template_id' in 'on clause'` iam getting this error

Comment: Then check what the tables and columns are actually called. The error message is pretty clear, and MYSQL does not just make them up because it is getting bored

Comment: columns and tables are called correctly

Comment: They cant be! Or you would not be getting this error message

Comment: Error message says `tbl_employee_payroll` is the table name? I dont see that table name in your queries???

Comment: what's is this `tbl_employee_payroll` ? there's not on your code

Comment: sorry it was employee by mistake it happens

Comment: You mean you used the wrong table name in the query, or the error message was wrong

Comment: the error message was wrong its like this `Unknown column 'employee.salary_template_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Please check for my answer it seems you are joining `attendance` in `salary employee join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it by changing my code like this

```
public function attendance_report_by_empid($user_id = null, $sdate = null) {

$this->db->select('attendance.*', FALSE);
$this->db->select('employee.*', FALSE);
$this->db->select('salary.*', FALSE);

$this->db->from('attendance');

$this->db->join('employee', 'employee.user_id  = attendance.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('salary', 'salary.salary_template_id  = employee.salary_template_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('attendance.user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->where('attendance.date_in', $sdate);
$this->db->where('attendance.date_out <=', $sdate);

$query_result = $this->db->get();
$result = $query_result->result();

return $query;
```

}

the problem was we have to declare the table before using that table for join.

Answer (score 0):

as per your desire output query should like this

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('attendence');
$this->db->join('salary'.'employee.salary_template_id', 'attendence.salary_template_id = table2.id',);
$this->db->join('employee', 'employee.user_id = attendance.user_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying join on wrong table

```
    $this->db->select('attendance.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('employee.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('salary.*', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('salary '); 
    $this->db->join('employee', 'salary.salary_template_id  = employee.salary_template_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('attendance', 'employee.user_id  = attendance.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('attendance.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('attendance.date_in', $sdate);
    $this->db->where('attendance.date_out <=', $sdate);
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
```

Comment: You were joining `$this->db->from('attendance');
    $this->db->join('salary', 'salary.salary_template_id  = employee.salary_template_id', 'inner');` attendance and salary and using employee in join

Comment: sorry for late replaying..i want to get it from attendance table in that manner i want to join